# get the list of values outside of loop-Python

Tags: python, list, newline

I want to get variable output a (which is in loop), outside of loop

```
        stopped_reasons = []
        output=[]




         client = boto3.client('ec2')
         reservations = client.describe_instances().get('Reservations', []) 

         for reservation in reservations:
             for instance in reservation['Instances']:
               tags = {}
               for tag in instance['Tags']:

                    tags[tag['Key']] = tag['Value']
                    if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
                      name=tag['Value']     
             if instance['State']['Name'] == 'stopped':

                 instance_ids.append(instance['InstanceId'])
                 instance_names.append(name)
                 stopped_reason = instance['StateTransitionReason']
                 stopped_reasons.append(stopped_reason)
                 transition_timestamp = datetime.strptime(instance['StateTransitionReason'][16:39], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')
                 #print (datetime.now() - transition_timestamp).days
                 a="Instance:"+ instance['InstanceId']  + '  Name: ' +name + "TIME: "+str(transition_timestamp)
                 print a
                 output.append(a)

print output
```

print a (inside loop) gives what i want:

```
Instance:i-03666a1aea6028cf0  Name: aws-opsworks-cm-instance-mypuppet-1541455366196TIME: 2018-11-15 18:30:27
Instance:i-0a67100fa09eab573  Name: Choco_ServerTIME: 2018-11-29 18:30:27
```

I'm trying to get same output but outside for loop. so i declared list output and appended a variable

but print output (outside loop) gives one line

```
['Instance:i-03666a1aea6028cf0  Name: aws-opsworks-cm-instance-mypuppet-1541455366196 TIME: 2018-11-15 18:30:27', 'Instance:i-0a67100fa09eab573  Name: Choco_Server TIME: 2018-11-29 18:30:27']
```

Answer (score 2):

just found it, have to join new line to the list

```
 body= "\n".join(output)
 print body
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you're using `output.append(a)` - `output` is a list. In general python prints lists like you see there: all in one line, with brackets, and with quotes around strings.

If you want to print each of the lines separately without the quotes, then you have to print *each element of the list individually*, rather than printing the whole list at once. Instead of

```
print output
```

do

```
for line in output:
    print line
```

Comment: thanks, but just found out another solution (see edited question)

Comment: If you did find a different solution, you should post it as an answer to your question, in order to help people in the future who might have the same issue.